# How can I get the data in my my Flexbox "rows" to line up at the top of each "cell", similar to a table?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get my layout aligned properly, but I am having trouble dialing in the "last mile".

In my example below, everything works just fine if the `message_data` `<span>` elements contain a single line of data. However, if one of those lines expands to multiple lines, it throws off the alignment of the rows within columns.

How can I get the `message_labels` and `message_data` to all align at the top of each row? Like in a data table.

**FLEXBOX NO DATA:**

```css
                html, body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    color: #313131;
                }
    
                #content {
                    margin: 2em;
                }
                
                #messages {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 50%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                
                .message_container {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    flex-wrap: nowrap;
                    justify-content: space-evenly;
                    background-color: #ffc0cb;
                    font-size: smaller;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message_controls {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: flex-start;
                    background-color: #dcdcdc;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    background-color: #87ceeb;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
    
                .message_headers {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                }
                
                .message_labels {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                    font-weight: 800;
                }
                
                .message_labels span {
                    margin: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message_data {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message_data span {
                    margin: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message_body {
                    font-family: monospace;
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head> </head>
        <body>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="messages">
                    <div class="message_container">
                        <div class="message_controls">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked>
                        </div> <!-- end message_controls div -->
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message_headers">
                                <div class="message_labels">
                                    <span>Label 01</span>
                                    <span>Label 02</span>
                                    <span>Label 03</span>
                                    <span>Label 04</span>
                                    <span>Label 05</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="message_data">
                                    <span>Data 01 ...</span>
                                    <span>Data 02 ...</span>
                                    <span>Data 03 ...</span>
                                    <span>Data 04 ...</span>
                                    <span>Data 05 ...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- end message_headers div -->
                            <div class="message_body">
                                <span>
                                    Text here ...
                                    <a href="#" target="_blank">[More]</a>
                                </span>
                            </div> <!-- end message_body div -->
                        </div> <!-- end message div -->
                    </div> <!-- end message_container div -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**FLEXBOX WITH DATA:**

```css
                html, body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    color: #313131;
                }
    
                #content {
                    margin: 2em;
                }
                
                #messages {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 50%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                
                .message_container {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    flex-wrap: nowrap;
                    justify-content: space-evenly;
                    background-color: #ffc0cb;
                    font-size: smaller;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message_controls {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: flex-start;
                    background-color: #dcdcdc;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    background-color: #87ceeb;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
    
                .message_headers {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                }
                
                .message_labels {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                    font-weight: 800;
                }
                
                .message_labels span {
                    margin: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message_data {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message_data span {
                    margin: 0.5em;
                }
                
                .message_body {
                    font-family: monospace;
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head> </head>
        <body>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="messages">
                    <div class="message_container">
                        <div class="message_controls">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked>
                        </div> <!-- end message_controls div -->
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message_headers">
                                <div class="message_labels">
                                    <span>Label 01</span>
                                    <span>Label 02</span>
                                    <span>Label 03</span>
                                    <span>Label 04</span>
                                    <span>Label 05</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="message_data">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque suscipit ex ac luctus blandit. Nulla dignissim turpis ac eros ultrices porttitor. Etiam efficitur neque urna, sit amet sodales lorem ultrices non. Quisque risus lorem, posuere et malesuada ac, malesuada id felis. Aliquam viverra libero eu dapibus blandit. Vivamus molestie vel nisl iaculis sodales. Fusce porttitor ultrices nisi at imperdiet. Curabitur sem neque, lobortis venenatis sagittis eu, interdum at quam. Duis vestibulum nulla sit amet neque aliquet, eget accumsan enim feugiat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam efficitur nec magna et molestie. Suspendisse elementum vel libero tristique varius. Donec dignissim tempor sagittis. Praesent nec rhoncus elit. Fusce ut leo urna.<br><br>Nullam luctus fringilla fringilla. Aliquam vehicula luctus nisi, rhoncus ultrices diam. Proin tempus pulvinar felis, eget ultrices nunc elementum in. Sed gravida felis vitae iaculis euismod. Sed dignissim luctus vulputate. Etiam ullamcorper lobortis lectus eu volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed pellentesque augue eu sodales gravida. Duis dapibus elit arcu, quis placerat ligula posuere vel.<br><br>Morbi tempor sagittis nibh non suscipit. Vivamus eu massa egestas, eleifend nisl eget, efficitur mauris. Aliquam commodo congue sodales. Nulla ornare nulla eu porttitor rutrum. Nullam lacinia sem ut lacinia fringilla. Fusce arcu diam, dictum lacinia eleifend quis, volutpat sed sapien. Sed imperdiet convallis libero, sed dapibus mauris lobortis nec. Mauris rhoncus tellus id tellus tempus, sed blandit tellus ullamcorper. Cras ultrices, ligula nec sagittis vestibulum, magna velit vehicula orci, ut dictum justo quam eget ipsum. Morbi accumsan libero eu dolor rhoncus condimentum. Vestibulum nec cursus nunc, eu mattis tellus. Duis tempor nisi dolor, id pretium ex tincidunt vel. Vivamus placerat augue interdum felis efficitur, vitae tempor lacus luctus. Maecenas placerat eros a velit condimentum, sed feugiat tellus tincidunt. Suspendisse a volutpat mauris. Nulla in feugiat diam, a ultricies ante.<br><br>Mauris tempus ut sem sed ultrices. Praesent in lobortis sem, eu pharetra ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec feugiat urna nec vestibulum consequat. Quisque vel ipsum a felis accumsan scelerisque nec nec magna. Maecenas sed neque imperdiet, convallis ligula non, rutrum libero. Nullam ultricies ex sed vulputate pretium. In id nisl orci. Sed imperdiet enim vestibulum, consequat lorem vel, accumsan justo.<br><br>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus hendrerit sed ipsum vitae ultricies. Aliquam sit amet erat a sem vulputate malesuada at at est. Nam hendrerit ultricies arcu, sed ultrices nulla egestas in. Cras eu mi iaculis, ornare sapien ut, placerat mi. Cras sed tellus pretium, tempus ex eget, congue purus. Nulla dignissim, sem quis fringilla varius, leo magna fringilla elit, vel placerat felis metus nec augue. Nullam eu ultrices tortor, sed vestibulum eros. Aliquam tincidunt placerat arcu. Proin vel scelerisque nisi. Vestibulum dictum auctor tristique. Etiam interdum a ligula sit amet maximus. Proin blandit pharetra diam, sit amet blandit ex euismod at. Quisque vel ex risus.</span>
                                    <span>Data 02 ...</span>
                                    <span>Data 03 ...</span>
                                    <span>Data 04 ...</span>
                                    <span>Data 06 ...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- end message_headers div -->
                            <div class="message_body">
                                <span>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean faucibus ante id augue malesuada feugiat. Vivamus vel ullamcorper velit. Pellentesque non lacinia risus. Ut efficitur orci id varius elementum. Morbi bibendum nisl purus, a molestie purus molestie vitae. Phasellus dignissim, est et cursus gravida, mauris urna hendrerit mauris, a maximus tortor lacus sit amet quam. Curabitur ac dolor vel sapien lacinia volutpat nec non massa. Ut tempor urna sed lacus fermentum, in ultrices dui luctus. Vivamus condimentum posuere velit iaculis gravida. Suspendisse ullamcorper tortor risus, sit amet lobortis arcu auctor vel. Aliquam blandit est quam, id cursus sapien varius eleifend.
                                    <a href="#" target="_blank">[More]</a>
                                </span>
                            </div> <!-- end message_body div -->
                        </div> <!-- end message div -->
                    </div> <!-- end message_container div -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**TABLE WITH DATA:**

```css
                html, body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    color: #313131;
                }
    
                #content {
                    margin: 2em;
                }
                
                #messages {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 50%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
    
                .label {
                    font-weight: 900;
                    vertical-align: top;
                }
    
                .data {
                    vertical-align: top;
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head> </head>
        <body>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="messages">
                    <div class="message_container">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Label 01</td>
                                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque suscipit ex ac luctus blandit. Nulla dignissim turpis ac eros ultrices porttitor. Etiam efficitur neque urna, sit amet sodales lorem ultrices non. Quisque risus lorem, posuere et malesuada ac, malesuada id felis. Aliquam viverra libero eu dapibus blandit. Vivamus molestie vel nisl iaculis sodales. Fusce porttitor ultrices nisi at imperdiet. Curabitur sem neque, lobortis venenatis sagittis eu, interdum at quam. Duis vestibulum nulla sit amet neque aliquet, eget accumsan enim feugiat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam efficitur nec magna et molestie. Suspendisse elementum vel libero tristique varius. Donec dignissim tempor sagittis. Praesent nec rhoncus elit. Fusce ut leo urna.<br><br>Nullam luctus fringilla fringilla. Aliquam vehicula luctus nisi, rhoncus ultrices diam. Proin tempus pulvinar felis, eget ultrices nunc elementum in. Sed gravida felis vitae iaculis euismod. Sed dignissim luctus vulputate. Etiam ullamcorper lobortis lectus eu volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed pellentesque augue eu sodales gravida. Duis dapibus elit arcu, quis placerat ligula posuere vel.<br><br>Morbi tempor sagittis nibh non suscipit. Vivamus eu massa egestas, eleifend nisl eget, efficitur mauris. Aliquam commodo congue sodales. Nulla ornare nulla eu porttitor rutrum. Nullam lacinia sem ut lacinia fringilla. Fusce arcu diam, dictum lacinia eleifend quis, volutpat sed sapien. Sed imperdiet convallis libero, sed dapibus mauris lobortis nec. Mauris rhoncus tellus id tellus tempus, sed blandit tellus ullamcorper. Cras ultrices, ligula nec sagittis vestibulum, magna velit vehicula orci, ut dictum justo quam eget ipsum. Morbi accumsan libero eu dolor rhoncus condimentum. Vestibulum nec cursus nunc, eu mattis tellus. Duis tempor nisi dolor, id pretium ex tincidunt vel. Vivamus placerat augue interdum felis efficitur, vitae tempor lacus luctus. Maecenas placerat eros a velit condimentum, sed feugiat tellus tincidunt. Suspendisse a volutpat mauris. Nulla in feugiat diam, a ultricies ante.<br><br>Mauris tempus ut sem sed ultrices. Praesent in lobortis sem, eu pharetra ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec feugiat urna nec vestibulum consequat. Quisque vel ipsum a felis accumsan scelerisque nec nec magna. Maecenas sed neque imperdiet, convallis ligula non, rutrum libero. Nullam ultricies ex sed vulputate pretium. In id nisl orci. Sed imperdiet enim vestibulum, consequat lorem vel, accumsan justo.<br><br>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus hendrerit sed ipsum vitae ultricies. Aliquam sit amet erat a sem vulputate malesuada at at est. Nam hendrerit ultricies arcu, sed ultrices nulla egestas in. Cras eu mi iaculis, ornare sapien ut, placerat mi. Cras sed tellus pretium, tempus ex eget, congue purus. Nulla dignissim, sem quis fringilla varius, leo magna fringilla elit, vel placerat felis metus nec augue. Nullam eu ultrices tortor, sed vestibulum eros. Aliquam tincidunt placerat arcu. Proin vel scelerisque nisi. Vestibulum dictum auctor tristique. Etiam interdum a ligula sit amet maximus. Proin blandit pharetra diam, sit amet blandit ex euismod at. Quisque vel ex risus.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Label 02</td>
                                <td>Data 02 ...</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Label 03</td>
                                <td>Data 03 ...</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Label 04</td>
                                <td>Data 04 ...</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Label 05</td>
                                <td>Data 05 ...</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean faucibus ante id augue malesuada feugiat. Vivamus vel ullamcorper velit. Pellentesque non lacinia risus. Ut efficitur orci id varius elementum. Morbi bibendum nisl purus, a molestie purus molestie vitae. Phasellus dignissim, est et cursus gravida, mauris urna hendrerit mauris, a maximus tortor lacus sit amet quam. Curabitur ac dolor vel sapien lacinia volutpat nec non massa. Ut tempor urna sed lacus fermentum, in ultrices dui luctus. Vivamus condimentum posuere velit iaculis gravida. Suspendisse ullamcorper tortor risus, sit amet lobortis arcu auctor vel. Aliquam blandit est quam, id cursus sapien varius eleifend.
    <a href="#" target="_blank">[More]</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr> <!-- end message_body div -->
                        </table> <!-- end message div -->
                    </div> <!-- end message_container div -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***** UPDATE 2

Here is another `grid` example which uses less markup.

```css
.table-grid {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 25px
}
```

```html
<div class="table-grid">
  <!-- ROW -->
  <div><strong>Label</strong></div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>

  <!-- ROW -->
  <div><strong>Label</strong></div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget mauris sagittis, dictum neque eu, tempor dui. Pellentesque et tellus eu magna condimentum fermentum. Curabitur ac felis non ante cursus sollicitudin sed quis velit. Integer volutpat
    lectus vitae bibendum ornare.</div>

  <!-- ROW -->
  <div><strong>Label</strong></div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

***** UPDATE

Here is an alternative using grid

```css
.table {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  background: slategray;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.table>li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80px 1fr;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="table">
  <li>
    <span>
<strong>Label</strong>
</span>
    <span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla et orci sagittis, aliquet mauris quis, facilisis ligula. Aenean vehicula lectus sit amet tellus ultricies, a semper orci pharetra. In pretium tincidunt fermentum. Duis massa massa, tempus quis mauris in, volutpat facilisis dui. 
</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
<strong>Label</strong>
</span>
    <span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla et orci sagittis, aliquet mauris quis, facilisis ligula. Aenean vehicula lectus sit amet tellus ultricies, a semper orci pharetra. In pretium tincidunt fermentum. Duis massa massa, tempus quis mauris in, volutpat facilisis dui. 
</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
<strong>Label</strong>
</span>
    <span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla et orci sagittis, aliquet mauris quis, facilisis ligula. Aenean vehicula lectus sit amet tellus ultricies, a semper orci pharetra. In pretium tincidunt fermentum. Duis massa massa, tempus quis mauris in, volutpat facilisis dui. 
</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Flexbox does not work like a table. You will need a "row" div like in the code below.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #313131;
}

#content {
  margin: 2em;
}

#messages {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.message_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #ffc0cb;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.message_controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #87ceeb;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.message_headers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message_labels {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.message_labels span {
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.message_data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.message-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.message-label {
  width: 80px;
}

.message_data span {
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.message_body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="messages">
      <div class="message_container">
        <div class="message_controls">
          <input type="checkbox" checked>
        </div>
        <!-- end message_controls div -->
        <div class="message">
          <div class="message_headers">

            <div class="message_data">
              <div class="message-row">
                <span class="message-label">Label 01</span>
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque suscipit ex ac luctus blandit. Nulla dignissim turpis ac eros ultrices porttitor. Etiam efficitur neque urna, sit amet sodales lorem ultrices non. Quisque risus lorem, posuere et malesuada ac, malesuada id felis. Aliquam viverra libero eu dapibus blandit. Vivamus molestie vel nisl iaculis sodales. Fusce porttitor ultrices nisi at imperdiet. Curabitur sem neque, lobortis venenatis sagittis eu, interdum at quam. Duis vestibulum nulla sit amet neque aliquet, eget accumsan enim feugiat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam efficitur nec magna et molestie. Suspendisse elementum vel libero tristique varius. Donec dignissim tempor sagittis. Praesent nec rhoncus elit. Fusce ut leo urna.<br><br>Nullam luctus fringilla fringilla. Aliquam vehicula luctus nisi, rhoncus ultrices diam. Proin tempus pulvinar felis, eget ultrices nunc elementum in. Sed gravida felis vitae iaculis euismod. Sed dignissim luctus vulputate. Etiam ullamcorper lobortis lectus eu volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed pellentesque augue eu sodales gravida. Duis dapibus elit arcu, quis placerat ligula posuere vel.<br><br>Morbi tempor sagittis nibh non suscipit. Vivamus eu massa egestas, eleifend nisl eget, efficitur mauris. Aliquam commodo congue sodales. Nulla ornare nulla eu porttitor rutrum. Nullam lacinia sem ut lacinia fringilla. Fusce arcu diam, dictum lacinia eleifend quis, volutpat sed sapien. Sed imperdiet convallis libero, sed dapibus mauris lobortis nec. Mauris rhoncus tellus id tellus tempus, sed blandit tellus ullamcorper. Cras ultrices, ligula nec sagittis vestibulum, magna velit vehicula orci, ut dictum justo quam eget ipsum. Morbi accumsan libero eu dolor rhoncus condimentum. Vestibulum nec cursus nunc, eu mattis tellus. Duis tempor nisi dolor, id pretium ex tincidunt vel. Vivamus placerat augue interdum felis efficitur, vitae tempor lacus luctus. Maecenas placerat eros a velit condimentum, sed feugiat tellus tincidunt. Suspendisse a volutpat mauris. Nulla in feugiat diam, a ultricies ante.<br><br>Mauris tempus ut sem sed ultrices. Praesent in lobortis sem, eu pharetra ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec feugiat urna nec vestibulum consequat. Quisque vel ipsum a felis accumsan scelerisque nec nec magna. Maecenas sed neque imperdiet, convallis ligula non, rutrum libero. Nullam ultricies ex sed vulputate pretium. In id nisl orci. Sed imperdiet enim vestibulum, consequat lorem vel, accumsan justo.<br><br>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus hendrerit sed ipsum vitae ultricies. Aliquam sit amet erat a sem vulputate malesuada at at est. Nam hendrerit ultricies arcu, sed ultrices nulla egestas in. Cras eu mi iaculis, ornare sapien ut, placerat mi. Cras sed tellus pretium, tempus ex eget, congue purus. Nulla dignissim, sem quis fringilla varius, leo magna fringilla elit, vel placerat felis metus nec augue. Nullam eu ultrices tortor, sed vestibulum eros. Aliquam tincidunt placerat arcu. Proin vel scelerisque nisi. Vestibulum dictum auctor tristique. Etiam interdum a ligula sit amet maximus. Proin blandit pharetra diam, sit amet blandit ex euismod at. Quisque vel ex risus.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="message-row">
                <span class="message-label">Label 01</span>
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque suscipit ex ac luctus blandit. Nulla dignissim turpis ac eros ultrices porttitor. Etiam efficitur neque urna, sit amet sodales lorem ultrices non. Quisque risus lorem, posuere et malesuada ac, malesuada id felis. Aliquam viverra libero eu dapibus blandit. Vivamus molestie vel nisl iaculis sodales. Fusce porttitor ultrices nisi at imperdiet. Curabitur sem neque, lobortis venenatis sagittis eu, interdum at quam. Duis vestibulum nulla sit amet neque aliquet, eget accumsan enim feugiat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam efficitur nec magna et molestie. Suspendisse elementum vel libero tristique varius. Donec dignissim tempor sagittis. Praesent nec rhoncus elit. Fusce ut leo urna.<br><br>Nullam luctus fringilla fringilla. Aliquam vehicula luctus nisi, rhoncus ultrices diam. Proin tempus pulvinar felis, eget ultrices nunc elementum in. Sed gravida felis vitae iaculis euismod. Sed dignissim luctus vulputate. Etiam ullamcorper lobortis lectus eu volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed pellentesque augue eu sodales gravida. Duis dapibus elit arcu, quis placerat ligula posuere vel.<br><br>Morbi tempor sagittis nibh non suscipit. Vivamus eu massa egestas, eleifend nisl eget, efficitur mauris. Aliquam commodo congue sodales. Nulla ornare nulla eu porttitor rutrum. Nullam lacinia sem ut lacinia fringilla. Fusce arcu diam, dictum lacinia eleifend quis, volutpat sed sapien. Sed imperdiet convallis libero, sed dapibus mauris lobortis nec. Mauris rhoncus tellus id tellus tempus, sed blandit tellus ullamcorper. Cras ultrices, ligula nec sagittis vestibulum, magna velit vehicula orci, ut dictum justo quam eget ipsum. Morbi accumsan libero eu dolor rhoncus condimentum. Vestibulum nec cursus nunc, eu mattis tellus. Duis tempor nisi dolor, id pretium ex tincidunt vel. Vivamus placerat augue interdum felis efficitur, vitae tempor lacus luctus. Maecenas placerat eros a velit condimentum, sed feugiat tellus tincidunt. Suspendisse a volutpat mauris. Nulla in feugiat diam, a ultricies ante.<br><br>Mauris tempus ut sem sed ultrices. Praesent in lobortis sem, eu pharetra ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec feugiat urna nec vestibulum consequat. Quisque vel ipsum a felis accumsan scelerisque nec nec magna. Maecenas sed neque imperdiet, convallis ligula non, rutrum libero. Nullam ultricies ex sed vulputate pretium. In id nisl orci. Sed imperdiet enim vestibulum, consequat lorem vel, accumsan justo.<br><br>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus hendrerit sed ipsum vitae ultricies. Aliquam sit amet erat a sem vulputate malesuada at at est. Nam hendrerit ultricies arcu, sed ultrices nulla egestas in. Cras eu mi iaculis, ornare sapien ut, placerat mi. Cras sed tellus pretium, tempus ex eget, congue purus. Nulla dignissim, sem quis fringilla varius, leo magna fringilla elit, vel placerat felis metus nec augue. Nullam eu ultrices tortor, sed vestibulum eros. Aliquam tincidunt placerat arcu. Proin vel scelerisque nisi. Vestibulum dictum auctor tristique. Etiam interdum a ligula sit amet maximus. Proin blandit pharetra diam, sit amet blandit ex euismod at. Quisque vel ex risus.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end message_headers div -->
            <div class="message_body">
              <span>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean faucibus ante id augue malesuada feugiat. Vivamus vel ullamcorper velit. Pellentesque non lacinia risus. Ut efficitur orci id varius elementum. Morbi bibendum nisl purus, a molestie purus molestie vitae. Phasellus dignissim, est et cursus gravida, mauris urna hendrerit mauris, a maximus tortor lacus sit amet quam. Curabitur ac dolor vel sapien lacinia volutpat nec non massa. Ut tempor urna sed lacus fermentum, in ultrices dui luctus. Vivamus condimentum posuere velit iaculis gravida. Suspendisse ullamcorper tortor risus, sit amet lobortis arcu auctor vel. Aliquam blandit est quam, id cursus sapien varius eleifend.
                                    <a href="#" target="_blank">[More]</a>
                                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- end message_body div -->
          </div>
          <!-- end message div -->
        </div>
        <!-- end message_container div -->
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Really ... there is no way to make all "cells" within  a row the same height, and push the data to the top? Seems pretty short-sighted in a world where people are constantly harangued for daring to use a table in "modern" HTML/CSS development.

Comment: @Brian table is still *modern* and will remain forever. What you want to do is simply a table and not suitable for flexbox so simply do it with table (or CSS grid if you can change the html)

Comment: I think using a table is totally fine. The reason tables got the bad reputation is because people in the old days were using it for layout. But if you need to display tabular data, i think it's fine.

Comment: @Brian remember that when building a table with CSS you are basically using the same principles as an HTML table. You will have a parent container with rows and cells. I like the GRID approach because you can set the `width` and `gap` properties right from the parent element. Hit me up if you want to go over the grid approach to creating a table.